# Как правильно создать объект для Multitouch?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал функцию для multitouch, но она немножко кривовата. У меня функция применяется для того, чтобы можно было пальцами перемещать квадратики (`div`-элементы) по несколько штук, в зависимости от количества касаний. Но проблема в том, что функцию приходится вызывать для каждого элемента отдельно, что не очень удобно, так как код увеличивается в размерах, плюс, возможно, самих дивов будет больше.

Вот пример функции для 2-х элементов:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('elem_1');
obj.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
  if (event.targetTouches.length == 1) {
    var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
    obj.style.left = touch.pageX + 'px';
    obj.style.top = touch.pageY + 'px';
  }
}, false);

var obj2 = document.getElementById('elem_2');
obj2.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
  if (event.targetTouches.length == 1) {
    var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
    obj2.style.left = touch.pageX + 'px';
    obj2.style.top = touch.pageY + 'px';
  }
}, false);
```

Как можно адаптировать функцию под любое количество элементов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждому квадратику задайте класс (например `.js-multitouch`), а код в js замените на:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elements = $('.js-multitouch');
  if (elements.length) {
    elements.each(function(e) {
      var element = $(this)
      element.bind('touchmove', function(event) {
        if (event.targetTouches.length == 1) {
          var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
          element[0].style.left = touch.pageX + 'px';
          element[0].style.top = touch.pageY + 'px';
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

В скрипте используется jQuery. В вашем коде он не встречается, но у вопроса стоит ярлык `jquery`, значит, если я верно понял - можно его использовать.

[Рабочий пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/fkevsnrd/)

Comment: Незнаю почему но так, не работает ...

Comment: Да, вы правы - проверил код на jsfiddle и исправил недочеты. Теперь будет работать.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Всё работает отлично